# Parsing generic tag in JSON from GSON

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I have a JSON which contains generic values. I tried it by using Maps but couldn't get the results. My problem is the generic tags starts from second level. Here is the JSON I am trying to parse through gson.

```
{
"success": true,
"status": 200,
"events": {
    "Sep 2013": [
        {
            "artist_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2013-05-18T15:21:00Z",
            "duration": 2,
            "end_time": "2013-09-19T22:00:00Z",
            "event_desc": "",
            "event_facebook_link": "",
            "event_link": "https://www.smtickets.com/marketing/view/1316",
            "feature_small": false,
            "featured_status": false,
            "id": 90,
```

In this JSON tag after "events" is generic i.e., "Sep 2013".

What I am trying right now is:

```
public Event event ;

public class Event {

    public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> dates;    

}
```

And I'm accessing it:

```
obj = gson.fromJson(reader, AllShowsActivityData.class);
```

Can anyone tell me that how can I make a class of dates. So Gson can serialize it. Or is there any other way to iterate first level tag and then I can declare it something like this

```
Type fooType = new TypeToken<Foo<Bar>>() {}.getType();
```

gson.toJson(foo, fooType);

Comment: As far as I know, with generic fiels you're screwed and can't map the JSON to some object automatically anymore. You'll have to parse through the JSON yourself with gson, sax-style.

Comment: Seriously :(...there must be some way to do it. In fact according to the https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types we can do it but its for the first level tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use a `Map`, but you're not using it correctly. Note that what you have is a field `"events"`, which is an object that contains a number of pairs `string` and `array` of objects:

```
{ "events": { "Sep 2013": [ {}, {}, ... ], ... } }
```

To parse your JSON you'd need a class structure like this (in *pseudo-code*):

```
class AllShowsActivityData
  Map<String, List<Event>> events

class Event
  int artist_id
  String created_at //parsing as String to simplify...
  int duration
  ...
```

And then your code to parse:

```
AllShowsActivityData obj = gson.fromJson(reader, AllShowsActivityData.class);
```

---

And finally, if what you want is to access the dates, you'll have all of them in:

```
Set<String> dates = obj.getEvents().keySet(); //"Sep 2013", ...
```

Note: in fact, if you only want those dates, you don't even need the class `Event` and you could use just `Map<String, List<Object>> events`...

Comment: @Hasandroid, just add more attributes to the class `Event` with names matching the field names in the JSON response, i.e., `String end_time`, `String event_desc`, etc... (it's easier for you to use just `String`, `int` and `boolean`). The just get an event object with `Event event = obj.getEvents().get(i);`, and then you can access all the fields in `event`...